# using print command's result as input value in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

im new bee in python, i have created a simple python script using Boto3 Library for AWS. Im simply creating a new Ec2 server, using boto3 which works fine but i need to use the print result and feed that result to another block of code which will terminate the Ec2. So my code looks like this:

```
import boto3
import botocore
import sys
import time
import threading
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
client = boto3.client('ec2')

# create a new Ec2 instance-AWS AMI Image
create = ec2.create_instances(
 ImageId='ami-041bdd9e494102',
 MinCount=1,
 MaxCount=1,
 InstanceType='t2.micro',
 KeyName='xyz', 
 SubnetId='subnet-1233541')
time.sleep(25) 

instances = ec2.instances.filter(
        Filters=[{
            'Name': 'instance-state-name', 
            'Values': ['running', 'stopped']}]
)
for instance in instances:
    time.sleep(20)
    print(instance.id, instance.instance_type, instance.state)`
## SO HERE I WANTED to execute the below code which will run after AFTER 40 Seconds and terminate the Instance which was launched previously

ec2.instances.filter(InstanceIds=ids).terminate()
```

Comment: What does this have anything to do with print command?

Comment: i just wanted to use the print result as an argument / input for the next block of code that will run after 40 sec. Lets assume the first block of code launches an EC2 instance with "id-xybz1234" and printed the result as output. with that being said, i need the id of instance to be used in the terminate instance part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this would work

```
for instance in instances:
    time.sleep(20)
    print(instance.id, instance.instance_type, instance.state)
    ec2.instances.filter(InstanceIds=[instance.id]).terminate()
```